# Android R.string value does not match with resource XML?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have the following code where I create a toast when a button is clicked.

```
Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
        String password = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
        try {
            firebaseRegister(email, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Register", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                R.string.registration_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Inside my `res/values/strings.xml` file, I have the following:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="registration_failed">Email invalid or already in use.</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

When I click the Register button, the text that shows up is:

- `Allow Ad to store image in Picture gallery?` (I don't have this string anywhere in my code)

Has anyone else seen something like this before? I expect it to say

- `Email invalid or already in use.`

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jorXd.jpg)

Comment: Can you double check to ensure you're including the right `R` class? _i.e._ not the global Android one? The R values are translated to just numbers, so I'd be it it's somehow looking in the wrong spot...

Comment: I think I'm using the global android `R` class, I don't import it anywhere. Is there another way I should be referencing strings?

In my android layout I have the three buttons and two Edit Text fields where, I reference all the buttons using `R.id.<value>`. Also, using `R.string.<value>` compiles okay, but `ca.my.package.R.string.<value>` throws an error

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: I did a blanket replace of all `R.*` to `ca.my.package.R.*` and that threw an AppCompat error where it couldn't cast my views. I since changed only the string resources to `ca.my.package.R.*`. Everything seems to work now. (Thanks again! I'm pretty new to Android, are strings the only resources where I have to explicitly reference with my package name? What's the difference between global `R` and `package.name.R`?)

Comment: Interesting. I'm not actually sure why you have to reference the FQN for strings only. Anyway, glad it works. The global one is the same conceptually as your package's, it just refers to different values (used by the Android system).

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project